# Newbie, how to install missing packages of C# and .net in visual studio or project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

[errors can be found here, in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcvtk.gif)

I am trying to use some library/packages

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SimplCommerce.Infrastructure.Data;
using SimplCommerce.Module.Core.Extensions;
using SimplCommerce.Module.Core.Models;
using SimplCommerce.Module.Orders.Services;
using SimplCommerce.Module.Orders.ViewModels;
```

In these, I am having error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore

and some package of internal structure like

> SimpleCommerce.Module.Core.

I am newbie in the visual studio and Microsoft tools so how I can resolve errors of using statements and another error I am getting is of 
C# version. I having C# 4 but the requirements of some of the projects are C# 5 so how I can upgrade version too.

[C#4 mean version error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlrV5.gif)

Thank you in advanced

Comment: `Nuget` is the term. Start researching from here.

Comment: usually this is done with NuGet. Right click on your project, "Manage NuGet packages..." and search for the packet.

Comment: Here is also another approach, if you want to add some .dll libraries to your project, you can add them on project reference, here is the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12992312/5132665 it is useful when you want to use some libraries which are not available on NuGet package manager.

Comment: Not only `Nuget`, question is more about Visual Studio version. You'll need VS 2017 for an easy support for NET Core

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas I know about Nuget but when I install the packages then they give me the error C# 4, you need C# 5 so how I can do that

Comment: @FıratÇağlarAkbulut thanks I got you

Comment: @mjwills can you check the image I have uploaded now??

Comment: if you dont have C#5 is probably the version of visual studio you are using. install an older version of the Nuget package that was built for that version of C#