# System.Speech.Synthesis: The type or namespace Speech does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

When I use the namespace
System.Speech.Synthesis
The speech is underlined and the error reads
The type or namespace name Speech does not exist in the namespace System

Help?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a reference to that DLL in your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992286/how-to-add-a-dll-reference-to-a-project-in-visual-studio